# Are the spans of two sets (each with two independent vectors in R2) isomorphic but not necessarily equal to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

The way I am thinking about it is **one set** of two vectors can create a plane (which is in R2) and the **other set** can create a different plane (also in R2). Both planes *do not need to be equal*, but are isomorphic to each other, correct?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$ there is only **one** plane, so they must necessarily be the same..

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the vectors are linearly independent.